# Call a JS function from and external file passing a parameter on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm kind of new to JS yet, so I'd like to know if there is anyway to do this:

main.js:

```
 $(function () {
   $('.delete_btn').click(function () {
      var confirmation = confirm('Deseja remover este evento?');
      if (!confirmation) return false;
   })
})

function updateIsoDate(date) {
   $('.datepicker').datepicker('setDate', date);
}
```

I'm already calling a function of it onload, but It doesn't required and specific thing.

events.ejs:

...

```
<div class="form-group">
       <label for="date">Data do Evento</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker"   id="date"name="date">
    <input type="hidden" id="dateInfo" name="date" value=' <%= event.date %>'>
</div>
```

...

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      updateIsoDate($('#dateInfo').val());
    });
  <script>
```

Can I call a function from a external file passing a parameter to it?
I don't know if I need to add scr="js/main.js" to my "script" tag cuz It's already previously loaded

So I'm trying to change my IsoDate format to display into my datepicker. It's working but I want to make the page a little cleaner calling it from another file.

**Kudos:**

First!Thanks everyone and especially Jonas w that made me realise something was wrong, and sorry for wasting your time.

**Answer:**

if you already inclued the js file previously, ex:

```
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
```

You can call you function from the script tag, and using

```
$(function () {'code here'}
```

or

```
 $(window).on('load', function () {'code here'}
```

You'll call it where the page is ready(1st one) or completely loaded(2nd one).

So calling your function and passing the argument/parameter, would be:

```
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
<script>
   $(window).on('load', function () {
      myFunc(arg);
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Just add the second script tag below the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

events.ejs:

I've add the javascript file

```
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
```

Here the input where the value is

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="date">Data do Evento</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker dp-add" id="date" name="date">
      <input type="hidden" id="dateInfo" name="date" value=' <%= event.date %>' required>
   </div>
    ...
```

Then used `$(window).on('load', function()` to pass the argument and call the function inside the main.js file

```
    <script>
    $(window).on('load', function() { 
        // Formating IsoDate to be displayed and setting into the datepicker
        updateIsoDate($('#dateInfo').val());
    });
    </script>
```

main.js:

```
function updateIsoDate(date) {
$('.datepicker').datepicker('setDate', date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpy do:

```
window.onload=function(){
coolonloadfunction("p1", "p2");
}
```

Or in Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
coolonloadfunction(" p1", "p2");
});
```

This executes:

```
function coolonloadfunction(a,b){
alert(a);//p1
alert(b);//p2
}
```

That may be in a different file, may be loaded with:

```
<script src=" scriptwithcoolonloadfunction.js"></script>
```

**Keep in mind that the external file should be placed in front of the code that calls functions in the file**

This answers the headline, however your real question is a bit unclear for me. Please specify

Comment: I'm already doing it, I want to call the function from a external file

Comment: @Johny Santana: Thats no problem. I still dont get your point

Comment: how do you :
1.Call a "function
2. From an external JS file
3.Passing a parameter 
4.On the page load?
Cuz your answer is lacking the key factor "calling a function from ajs file".

Comment: @Johnny Santana : all js files are executed in the "window" scope wich means they can interact easily

Comment: wtf I tested It and It was not working.. I even thought It was because of the $(document).. but it's working on both $(window) and $(document). Thanks for your time

Comment: @Johnny Santana: Please put your whole pagecode into the answer, to let us check whats wrong

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you move

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      updateIsoDate($('#dateInfo').val());
    });
<script>
```

to your **main.js**, so in result you will have:

```
function updateIsoDate(date) {
   $('.datepicker').datepicker('setDate', date);
}
$(function () {
   $('.delete_btn').click(function () {
      var confirmation = confirm('Deseja remover este evento?');
      if (!confirmation) return false;
   })
   $(document).ready(function () {
      updateIsoDate($('#dateInfo').val());
   });
})
```

Comment: My code is already on main.js. I want to pass and argument/parameter to it on the load of the page

Comment: $(document).ready(function () will launch your function at DOM creation.

Either way your option will also work if you put codes like:
<script scr="js/main.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      updateIsoDate($('#dateInfo').val());
    });
  <script>

Both ways will work.

Or maybe I don't get what's the problem with code? Try to console.log('test') somewhere to check if the code is launched